# Vaadin configuration with BIRT

Tags: web.xml, vaadin, birt

I'm useing Vaadin and BIRT reporting in my project.I have problem with accessing report with Vaadin,I think its related to my web.xml configuration.Can anyone help me to get out from this problem??

```
< /servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyProject/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If i put url pattern like this.it shows index.jsp page as first page.

```
< /servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If I configure the url pattern as "/*" it works fine and load the vaadin UI

but the problem is if I put 2nd configuration I can not load the report to browser,It always redirect to my current vaadin UI page (When I click the button to load the report)

If put first configuration I can access report directly ,But It does not load the vaadin UI.

Can any one help me to solve this problem??

Thank you.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first configuration should be ok, but you have to access your application differently:

Try

```
http://localhost:8080/[display-name]/MyProject
```

You should find the display-name right above the first context-param

```
<display-name>IamTheDisplayName</display-name>
<context-param>
    <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```